# How to find the recording time for a video from the linux command line

Tags: linux, video, timestamp, command-line-interface, mpeg

I have some `mpeg`s from my [camcorder](http://www.sonystyle.com/webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/ProductDisplay?storeId=10151&catalogId=10551&langId=-1&productId=8198552921665291492) and I'm trying to figure out when they were recorded.

So far, I have tried [transcode](http://www.transcoding.org):

```
 tcprobe -i M2U00249.MPG -H 10 -d258
```

Which resulted in:

```
[scan_pes.c] SCR=       0 (       0) unit=0 @ offset     0.0000 (sec)
[tcprobe] MPEG program stream (PS)
[tcprobe] summary for M2U00249.MPG, (*) = not default, 0 = not detected
import frame size: -g 720x480 [720x576] (*)
 aspect ratio: 16:9 (*)
   frame rate: -f 29.970 [25.000] frc=4 (*)
               PTS=0.2057, frame_time=33ms bitrate=9100 kbps
  audio track: -a 0 [0] -e 48000,16,5 [48000,16,2] -n 0x2000 [0x2000] (*)
               PTS=0.0895, bitrate=448 kbps
               -D 3 --av_fine_ms 16 (frames & ms) [0] [0]
```

[MPlayer:](http://www.mplayerhq.hu)

```
 mplayer -identify M2U00249.MPG
```

Which resulted in:

```
Playing M2U00249.MPG.
ID_VIDEO_ID=0
ID_AUDIO_ID=128
MPEG-PS file format detected.
VIDEO:  MPEG2  720x480  (aspect 3)  29.970 fps  9100.0 kbps (1137.5 kbyte/s)
ID_FILENAME=M2U00249.MPG
ID_DEMUXER=mpegps
ID_VIDEO_FORMAT=0x10000002
ID_VIDEO_BITRATE=9100000
ID_VIDEO_WIDTH=720
ID_VIDEO_HEIGHT=480
ID_VIDEO_FPS=29.970
ID_VIDEO_ASPECT=0.0000
ID_AUDIO_FORMAT=8192
ID_AUDIO_BITRATE=0
ID_AUDIO_RATE=0
ID_AUDIO_NCH=0
ID_START_TIME=0.09
ID_LENGTH=122.06
ID_SEEKABLE=1
ID_CHAPTERS=0
```

[FFmpeg](http://ffmpeg.org):

```
ffprobe -show_format -show_streams M2U00243.MPG
```

Which resulted in:

```
index=0
codec_name=mpeg2video
codec_long_name=MPEG-2 video
codec_type=video
codec_time_base=1001/60000
codec_tag_string=[0][0][0][0]
codec_tag=0x0000
width=720
height=480
has_b_frames=1
sample_aspect_ratio=32:27
display_aspect_ratio=16:9
pix_fmt=yuv420p
id=0x1e0
r_frame_rate=30000/1001
avg_frame_rate=30000/1001
time_base=1/90000
start_time=0.178456
duration=282.682400
[/STREAM]
[STREAM]
index=1
codec_name=ac3
codec_long_name=ATSC A/52A (AC-3)
codec_type=audio
codec_time_base=0/1
codec_tag_string=[0][0][0][0]
codec_tag=0x0000
sample_rate=48000.000000
channels=6
bits_per_sample=0
id=0x80
r_frame_rate=0/0
avg_frame_rate=125/4
time_base=1/90000
start_time=0.079722
duration=282.720000
[/STREAM]
[FORMAT]
filename=M2U00243.MPG
nb_streams=2
format_name=mpeg
format_long_name=MPEG-PS format
start_time=0.079722
duration=282.781134
size=330334208.000000
bit_rate=9345296.000000
[/FORMAT]
```

None of these seems to have the time that the video was recorded. Is there something I'm missing or is the only way to get the recording time:

```
stat -c %y M2U00249.MPG
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no required record of the absolute encode time in an MPEG program stream. Getting the last modified time from the file system is your best bet.

Answer (score 0):

I use `mediainfo` to get the recorded date of videos. I've not tried it with MPGs, but I shouldn't think it will be any different.

```
sudo apt-get -y install mediainfo
```

And then `mediainfo <filename>`

Or `mediainfo -f <filename>` for full verbosity

Answer (score 0):

https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=278052

> apt-get install **mediainfo-gui**

in nemo or caja, right click on .mp4, then choose other application, Mediainfo-gui, choose view --> Html, and Debug --> Complete